# Alter the structure of the DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

I am currently working on a project where I read different .csv files into a DataFrame and perform various operations on it, as required. For one of the tasks, I have DF with the first column containing datetime and the other containing corresponding values.

I need to convert the below DF:

```
1/04/2013 0:00  1.131  
1/04/2013 0:30  0.83  
1/04/2013 1:00  0.19  
1/04/2013 1:30  0.44  
1/04/2013 2:00  0.9  
1/04/2013 2:30  1.131  
1/04/2013 3:00  0.56  
2/04/2013 0:00  1.131  
2/04/2013 0:30  0.83  
2/04/2013 1:00  0.19  
2/04/2013 1:30  0.44  
2/04/2013 2:00  0.9  
2/04/2013 2:30  1.131  
2/04/2013 3:00  0.56
```

To the below structure:

```
1/04/2013   1.131   0.83    0.19    0.44    0.9 0.56    0.56  
2/04/2013   1.131   0.83    0.19    0.44    0.9 1.131   0.56
```

So basically, get the common date and then the corresponding values in each row.

I have had a look into the DataFrame documentation however, I am unable to get my head around how to convert it into such a structure.

I am using pandas 0.20.3 with Python 3.6.2

Any help on this will be great. Thank you.

**UPDATE**
Here are few lines from the .csv file. (One year worth of data)

```
Account Number,NMI,DeviceNumber,DeviceType,RegisterCode,RateTypeDescription,StartDate,EndDate,ProfileReadValue,RegisterReadValue,QualityFlag
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2013 0:00,1/04/2013 0:29,1.131,0,A
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2013 0:30,1/04/2013 0:59,1.131,0,A
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2013 1:00,1/04/2013 1:29,1.131,0,A
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2013 1:30,1/04/2013 1:59,1.131,0,A
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2013 2:00,1/04/2013 2:29,1.131,0,A
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2013 2:30,1/04/2013 2:59,1.131,0,A
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2013 3:00,1/04/2013 3:29,1.131,0,A
.
.
.
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2014 21:30,1/04/2014 21:59,1.131,0,A
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2014 22:00,1/04/2014 22:29,1.131,0,A
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2014 22:30,1/04/2014 22:59,1.131,0,A
12345678,123456789,123456,xxxx,666666#B1,x,1/04/2014 23:00,1/04/2014 23:29,1.131,0,A
```

I take the 6th and 8th column (Index starting from zero)

**Code to get the df from csv**

```
df = pd.read_csv(
filename,
header=None,
skiprows=1,
nrows=17568,
skip_blank_lines=True,
usecols=[6,8],
converters={6: lambda d: datetime.strptime(str(d), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") 
if d else None}
)
```

Comment: Including header and index would help to provide a reproducible solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it to work. I tried a different approach but it wouldn't have been possible without all the help provided by @FabienP.

```
headers = ['StartDate', 'ProfileReadValue']  
try:    
df = pd.read_csv(
  filename,
  skiprows=1,
  names=headers,          
  nrows=17568,
  skip_blank_lines=True,
  usecols=[6,8],       
  converters={6: lambda d: datetime.strptime(str(d), "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") if d 
  else None}     
  ) 
df = df.set_index([df.StartDate.dt.date,df.StartDate.dt.time]).ProfileReadValue.rename_axis([None] * 2).unstack()  
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

So , I set the headers for both the columns first. Had to skip the first row otherwise the converter fails on the first row. Then ised the headers to set the index using the date and time from datetime and then unstack the df.

As I needed the date values in the df, I used the reset index to put in the df. Gave me the desired output.

The final shape for the df was (366,49) as required.

Comment: Glad you finally built a solution on you own :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the provided tables are the values itself, so first column is not an index:

```
s = pd.Series(df.iloc[:, 1].values,
              index=pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:, 0], dayfirst=True))

s.resample('1D').aggregate(lambda x: x.tolist())
Out[]:
0
2013-04-01    [1.131, 0.83, 0.19, 0.44, 0.9, 1.131, 0.56]
2013-04-02    [1.131, 0.83, 0.19, 0.44, 0.9, 1.131, 0.56]
dtype: object
```

Where `df` is formatted as a `pandas.Series` `s`:

1. `s` values are that `df` of column 1
2. `s` index is `df` column 0 converted to type `datetime`

`iloc[:, <col_index>]` is used to access the columns independently of their names, which are not provided in the question.

Then the formatting of the data itself `s.resample('1D').apply(lambda x: x.tolist())` where:

1. `resample('1D')` groups the data based on index with a frequency of 1 day
2. `aggregate` applies a the below function on each group
3. `lambda x: x.tolist()` converts a series to `list`

Is it what you're looking for?

---

EDIT1: fix typo in explanations

---

**EDIT2: Correct code for csv file sample**

From the CSV file sample provided, the following code should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv("input_file_name.csv", sep=",",index_col=6, parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)

df.resample('1D').ProfileReadValue.aggregate(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

Output should look like that:

```
StartDate
2013-04-01    [1.131, 1.131, 1.131, 1.131, 1.131, 1.131, 1.131]
dtype: object
```

Note that there is only one day in the sample, and that this code relies on the name of the data column `ProfileReadValue` being stable.

Comment: Just to give you more context, the .csv file contains just a little more than one year worth of data. 366 days. Each day has 48 intervals with their corresponding values.  So in total of 17568 rows. When I read the .csv file, I convert the first column to DateTime using converters. The output you have shown is what I was looking for. The final shape of Dataframe should be like (366,49). Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hi @FabienP. Thanks heaps for the help. I was just wondering, you mentioned **s index is df column 2 converted to type datetime.** Actually, I wanted it the other way round. [DateTime, v1, v2, v3, v4]. Meaning the first column is datetime followed by values. Your output is perfect and the I can see in the code that you use the values from the second column and datetime from 1st column. That's how I want it. Unable to make it work

Comment: Sorry "column 2" was a typo, it's from column 0. Corrected. Do you get an error? Could you post the first few lines of your CSV? It would be easier to fix the code working with real data.

Comment: I've updated the question now. I want to return a dataframe in the structure we discussed. Unable to do so directly, even if I convert the series to a dataframe.

Comment: @Avi_B, updated my answer to match your data, should work now if you use the right file name in `read_csv` of course.